# PHP и mySQL: Как сделать регестрацию на одном с сохранением по http (s) на другой сайт в БД

Tags: php, mysql, sql, http, https

Как сделать чтобы регистрируясь на одном сайте можно было сохранять информацию в БД другого сайта и соответственно  вход также подключения к стороннему сайту - БД.
Люди  которые знают источники, где можно посмотреть пример, прошу писать в коментарии.

Comment: Слишком мало входных данных. Есть ли у вас доступ к БД другого сайта? Есть ли у другого сайта какой-то API?

Comment: Доступ ко все есть и к БД и к сайту! Просто что именно нужно посмотреть как пример чтоб понять с чего начать и что к чему... Может у вас есть какой то пример с ссилкой...

Comment: опишите задачу целиком, иначе тут слишком много вариантов

Comment: Есть некий сайт **сайт1.ком** на нем есть форма регистрации и форма входа на сайт! С этого сайта нужно осуществить регистрацию и вход на **сайт2.ком** и сохранить дание в БД на сайт **сайт2.ком**! Доступ к **сайт2.ком** есть! Может знаете какой-нибудь пример где можно посмотреть/прочитать ссылку на какой-то англо сайт например?? Или какую-то книгу где там есть пример передачи данных в бд другого сайта по http(s) протоколу!